# Keep password in memory

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to keep the user's files encrypted. This part I've achieved easily by using Java's built-in cryptography library. Loading the file from the disk is done by reading the salt from an attached file, having the user input the password, and then generating the salted and hashed key, which is then quickly disposed. But when it comes to saving the files back to the disk, a problem arises because I need to keep the key in memory throughout the whole runtime, or have the user input the password every time I write the file to the disk. What would you recommend in order to keep my application as secure as possible.

Comment: Remember to generate a new salt every time you encrypt anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be as secure as possible then your user should enter the password again. However really you need to look at the use-case and decide what you are defending against.

For example if they have to enter the password again then they are more vulnerably to someone shoulder surfing or key loggers, etc but the increased risk is pretty small.

The password kept in memory is only vulnerable to processes already running on the machine the software is running on. That again is a pretty small risk as it would probably be easier just for them to put a key logger on.

So really in this sort of scenario the main risk factors are the people. Can someone trick the person entering the password into revealing it (i.e. spear fishing, fake login prompts, key loggers, shoulder surfing). Mitigating most of those risks is about training, not about technical issues at all.

Far too many people think that a technical silver bullet can solve all their security woes. It really can't, a system is only as secure as its weakest link and you need to think about the big picture as well as the small one.